# How can I show that ℝ[x] is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I figured that I'd start out by assuming (by way of contradiction) that ℝ[x] *is* finitely generated, and then showing that no matter what finite generator set I have, there's some element outside of its span.

But...I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Finitely generates as what? An Abelian Group? Vector space? Ring? It is also an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, but **is** finitely generated in that context...

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean to show that it is not finitely-generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-module. (And I also suspect that you probably mean to a consider an arbitrary ring $R$ and not the ring of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, but no matter.)

Take a finite set of polynomials $p_1(x), \dots, p_n(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and let $d_1, \dots, d_n$ be their respective degrees. Then any $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of the polynomials has degree $\leq \max(d_1, \dots, d_n)$. In particular, if $d > \max(d_1, \dots, d_n)$, then $x^d$ does not belong to the $\mathbb{R}$-span of your polynomials, proving that they do not generate $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: There it is. Thank you!